# Intellij Idea fails to sync with Gradle: JvmOptions error

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to open freshly created Gradle project in Intellij Idea 2020.1. However, when trying to sync with Gradle, either on startup or manually, Idea shows the following text in "build" window:

```
'void org.gradle.process.internal.JvmOptions.<init>(org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileCollectionFactory)''void org.gradle.process.internal.JvmOptions.<init>(org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileCollectionFactory)'
```

and the project is not being imported.

I'm not able to find any references to this error. Could you give me some hints on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data). A sample project to reproduce would be also helpful.

Comment: For me this is reproduced on every project, even on the one freshly created by Idea itself. Thanks for the hint, I'll post the problem there.

Comment: Try the clean IDE install from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. See if there is any global Gradle configuration that can affect it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turned out to be the issue with incorrect updating.

As I found, the Gradle plugin in my Intellij Idea installation contained two copies of Gradle libraries, for two different version of Gradle. In the fresh installation of Intellij Idea, there is only the Gradle 6.1. By removing the old version of Gradle from the plugin, problem was resolved.

Comment: it works for me after removing four 5.2.1 jar files from \plugins\gradle\lib , where there are also similar set of files with version 6.1.1

Comment: where is  "\plugins\gradle\lib" path on mac? @BeeChow

Comment: can you search in finder?